# Remote execution using docker - how to retrieve result

Tags: docker, remote-server

I have a powerful desktop machine (workstation) and a weak laptop. I'd like to offhand compilation to the workstation, but I'm a bit puzzled as to how to retrieve the result.

docker build correctly sends the build environment to the remote daemon, and compiles the code, but I'm not sure how to retrieve the result. Ideally it would merge the changes back to my working dir

`docker build PATH` should:

1. send anything not .dockerignored to the remote from `PATH` (done)
2. run the build commands described in the Dockerfile (done)
3. retrieve the results and merge changes into the `PATH`. (???)

Another approach would be to set up a share of PATH into the container, and run a container that does the build, but that doesn't work if the daemon is remote, and I would like a general solution, without having to set up NFS shares between the laptop & workstation, because my setup is too dynamic for that. I'd love this to work from any machine that is set up with the correct `DOCKER_HOST`.

Comment: Did you check `docker image ls` doesn't contain the resulted image?

Comment: I would suggest a solution based on plain ssh (or an old-school task queue system), and not using Docker for this.  It's tricky to copy results out of built Docker images, so your "retrieve the results" step isn't going to be easy (the best way is to `docker start` a container and then `docker cp` out of it).  There are also some really big security implications to a remote `DOCKER_HOST`: if you don't have a correct TLS client certificate setup then you've effectively opened up remote root access to the system to _anyone_.

Comment: Security implications are not important, I'm usually either on my own LAN, or VPNed into my LAN, so opening it up to the network should be okay. Do I need to start a container before I can cp out of it?